# No qualifying bean of type repository when running test but not main application

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, spring-bean

I'm developing a Spring Boot application following TDD methodology. I've created the main classes (controller, service and repository) this way:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class CrimeServiceImpl implements CrimeService{

    @Autowired
    private CrimeRepository repository;
    ...
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class CrimeController {

    @Autowired
    private CrimeServiceImpl service = new CrimeServiceImpl();
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface CrimeRepository extends JpaRepository<Crime, Long>{

}
```

This is the project structure:

[image]

If I run the application normally, no error. The classes' methods are empty. Then I've created a test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CrimeServiceImpl.class)
@ComponentScan("com.springmiddleware")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class TestCrimeService {

    //Calling method getAllCrimes works
    @Test
public void returnAllCrimesExists() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    List<Crime> list = new ArrayList<>();
    assertTrue(this.service.getAllCrimes() == list);

}
```

And if I run this, the following error is shown and the test fails:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.springmiddleware.repository.CrimeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

I've checked all annotations and it seems to me that all is ok, and I thought if I missed something, even in the normal run the application would fail. What did I got wrong?

Comment: `@Autowired
    private CrimeServiceImpl service = new CrimeServiceImpl();`: that makes no sense. First, if you write an interface for your service, then use it. Second, the whole point of dependency injection is to let the framework inject the service instance in your controller, and to avoid creating it by yourself. Your test is also very unclear: what are you trying to test? Testing that a class has a method is useless.

Comment: @JBNizet testing that the method exists is just me giving it a try. The error is not caused by me doing useless tests, it would remain also if I changed the test.

Comment: you may want to use `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)` and `@MockBean` annotation. no time to put that into a good answer (in short: you only test the controller-layer for now, no underlying beans), but here are some links I could share: https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/07/31/guide-spring-boot-controller-tests/ 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ That said, please, PLEASE stop using setter-based injection via @Autowired, use constructor-injection instead (see here why: https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/29/how-not-to-hate-spring-in-2016) - also see what @JB Nizet says. Makes sense.

Comment: But since the test makes no sense, we can't explain you how to best write the test, since we have no idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The test is now 

Test
 public void returnAllCrimesExists() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
  List<Crime> list = new ArrayList<>();
  assertTrue(this.service.getAllCrimes() == list);
  
 }

The error is the same. I added also WebMvcTest and MockBean

Comment: If you're just trying to unit test the service code, which is still not clear given that you won't tell us what you want to achieve, and the code you just posted still doesn't make sense, then remove all the annotations on your test class. They're useless for a unit test.

Comment: I'm trying to follow TDD approach (I said that in the question) by testing simple things first, I really don't get what is unclear

Comment: Also, I've already did this kind of test just not following a TDD approach, and they did work

Comment: It makes no sense because you're adding a whole lot of useless annotations (and we thus wonder why you chose to add them), because your code doesn't compile (where is `this.service` defined?), and because even if it did compile, the test can't possibly pass. Again, if your goal is to unit test the service, then learn about mocking to mock the repository and create a service using a mock repository, and remove all the annotations on your test class.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted also to make a test class for a JPARepository, and I also encountered the same error message:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
> 'SomethingRepository' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

I could make it work by adding the 2 following annotations on top of the test class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = SomethingRepository.class) // repository
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Something.class) // entity of the repository
```

Now it looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = SomethingRepository.class) // repository
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Something.class) // entity of the repository
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyDbUnitTestApp.class) // does some @ComponentScan and @EntityScan on the repositories/entities package, and @EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.myTestProfile)
@DatabaseSetup(value = {
        "/datasets/dataset1.xml" }, type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
public class SomethingRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomethingRepository sut;

    @Test
    public void findById() {

        Something something= sut.findById(1L);

        Assert.assertEquals("foobar", something.getName());
    }

}
```